When is 4 qualitatively different than $n\leq 3$?
Inspired by When is 2 qualitatively different from 3?
Also similar to Are there mathematical concepts that exist in dimension 4, but not in dimension 3? (Math SE), but with the restriction of being regular up to $n=3$.
There are many examples of when 3 is different from 2, but I would have liked to have the follow-up question. What are mathematical features that are more or less regular up to 3 but change dramatically in complexity when the number is increased to 4?
For the moment I can only think of examples of higher orders, like polynomials of order 5 having no general solution. Maybe this question can be extended to the next $n$.

There are plenty of examples of $n=4$ being weird in topology, e.g. exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$’s.

When the $n$-th post of the series will get no answer, we could conclude that $n+1$ is not qualitatively different from $1,\dots, n$, therefore it is qualitatively different.

I’m voting to close this question because one can keep up this type of question ad infinitum

I'm voting to close the integers because one can keep up that type of number ad infinitum.

I'm voting that we write a script to copy the answers back and forth between this question and the other one, inserting "+1"'s and "-1"'s as needed.

In all seriousness, I think I'd actually get something out of perusing more lists like this. It reminds me of John Baez's "my favorite numbers" articles.

Are you aware that [tag:gm.general-mathematics] is the part of the arXiv where all the crank 3-page "proofs" of the Riemann Hypothesis/Goldbach Conjecture/FLT/PvsNP go? I find it mildly surprising that people use it here on MO, but perhaps the community here has rehabilitated the label...

@DavidRoberts I am the one that added gm.general-mathematics to the original 2 vs. 3 question; I assume the tags were reused here as they are in the other question. I thought the guideline is that every question should have a "top-level" Arxiv tag, and gm looked like the only fitting one. Feel free to remove it if you disagree! And if this tag has a special meaning, I suggest making it clear in its tag wiki.

@DavidRoberts Reading your comment, I expected that 4-page proofs belong to other arXiv category, that makes the difference.

@FedorPetrov well done :-)

@FedericoPoloni You are correct on the guideline, and generic questions like this that don't fit into a specific top-level tag are a bit of an oddity. Sometimes the [tag:ho.history-overview] tag is more appropriate. I don't think the math.gm bucket has a special meaning here on MO as it does on the arXiv, it's just something I find a bit unusual.

@PietroMajer, this won't ever happen because $n$ and $n+1$ have different parity with implications. An answer "$\mathbb{R}^n$  admits a symplectic structure and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ doesn't" for one question will be followed by "$\mathbb{R}^n$  admits a contact structure and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ doesn't" for the next one.

I am with Tim Campion on this. I would like to see this question for 4 vs 5. (I think 3 vs 4 is a somewhat over-debated case because of 3 vs 4 dimensions being somewhat special for us; on the other hand, many answers here do not focus on geometry).

@M.Winter You are free to create the next level post.

The free modular lattice on $n$ generators is finite if $n\leq 3$ and infinite if $n\geq 4$.

There are no genuinely quantum permutations on $N\leq 3$ symbols but there are from $N=4$.
The quantum permutation group $S_N^+$ on $N$ symbols is a virtual object given the unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $C(S_N^+)$ generated by the entries of an $N\times N$ magic unitary. A magic unitary is a matrix with entries in a unital *-algebra whose entries are orthogonal projections and whose rows and columns sum to the identity.
This algebra admits a compact quantum group structure.
For $N\leq 3$, the algebra is commutative and in fact by Gelfand theory isomorphic to the algebra of continuous (aka all) functions on the symmetric group. From $N=4$ the algebra is noncommutative and we have a "genuine" quantum group.

Please could you add a link or define quantum permutation?

@MarkWildon added a bit there.

The word problem is decidable in every $\leq3$-manifold group, but can be undecidable in $4$-manifold groups.

For $n\leq3$, all groups of order $n$ are isomorphic, but there are two nonisomorphic groups of order $4$.

To say nothing of the three groups of order $6$!

Let $K$ be an infinite field. Fix $N \ge 2$ and consider $n$-tuples of subspace of a vector space $K^N$ up to the diagonal action of $\mathrm{GL}_N(K)$. There are finitely many isomorphism classes if $n \le 3$ and infinitely many whenever $n \ge 4$.
In the language of representation theory, the star quiver with $n$ leaves has finite representation type if and only if $n \le 3$.

Is this related to the undirected graph of the star quiver being a Dynkin diagram up to $n = 3$, but not after?

Yes. Gabriel's Theorem is that the module category of a quiver algebra over an infinite field has finite type if and only if the underlying undirected graph of the quiver is of Dynkin type A, D or E.

Maybe worth noting that for $N = 2$ this is just the fact that any $3$ points in $\mathbb{P}^1$ are  projectively equivalent, but for $4$ points the cross-ratio is an invariant.

Note that $n=4$ is also qualitatively different from $n\ge 5$ since the star quiver with four leaves is an affine Dynkin diagram, so has tame representation type (while the representation type is wild for $n\ge 5$).

Showing that, when the next iteration of this question comes around, we can copy and paste this answer with minor changes.

Riemannian geometry in dimensions 4 and higher is often quite different compared to two- and three-dimensional geometry, due to the Ricci decomposition. For surfaces, the entire Riemann curvature tensor can be determined from the scalar curvature alone. In three dimensions, the Ricci curvature suffices to determine the entire Riemann curvature tensor. However, in higher dimensions there is the Weyl tensor, which plays an important role in the analysis of higher-dimensional manifolds.
It's probably not possible to give a complete list for all the places where this distinction manifests itself, but one example is in the analysis of Ricci flow. In three-dimensions, the eigenvalues of the Ricci tensor evolve in a relatively well-controlled way, which gives rise to an effect known as Hamilton-Ivey pinching. This plays a crucial role in understanding the possible geometry of singularities, but fails in higher dimensions (unless one imposes much stronger assumptions on the geometry).

What about General Relativity ?
See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00762914 .

In ordinal analysis, an analysis of the theory $\mathrm{KP}+\Pi_3\text{-reflection}$ was first published by Rathjen in 1994 (Rathjen, "Proof Theory of Reflection"), the function on ordinals used to obtain the ordinal notation has a definition (definition 4.8) that only is about a third of a page long. At the end of this paper, Rathjen provides a similarly simple ordinal function for a future analysis of $\mathrm{KP}+\Pi_4\text{-reflection}$, but as far as I know this turned out to be incorrect as the function used did not account for complexities that arose when trying to carry out the analysis.
Since then, all published definitions become much more complex when attempting to analyze $\mathrm{KP}+\Pi_4\text{-reflection}$. Some analyses exist, however the ordinal functions appearing in them have much longer definitions, for example:

In Duchhardt's 2008 dissertation Thinning Operators and $\Pi_4$-Reflection, the definition (pp. 17–19) is just over two pages.
In Arai's later paper "A simplified ordinal analysis of first-order reflection", the definition (definitions 2.4–2.5) is about one and a half pages, or two and a half if including the preliminary definitions of definition 2.1 which are not standard material. (This is a stronger function defined in aiming for a stronger result than ordinal analysis of $\mathrm{KP}+\Pi_4\text{-reflection}$, but the $N=4$ case will give the desired result and a definition of the same length.)


This complexity increase has been remarked on by a few different people:

An ordinal analysis of $\Pi_\omega\text-\mathsf{Ref}$ requires a transfinite iteration of techniques needed for an ordinal analysis of $\Pi_3\text-\mathsf{Ref}$ as published in [Rat94b]. The ordinal analysis of $\Pi_4\text-\mathsf{Ref}$ given by Christoph Dichhardt in [Duc08] reveals that even a finite iteration of these techniques is far from being trivial.

~ Stegert, in his 2010 dissertation Ordinal proof theory of Kripke-Platek set theory augmented by strong reflection principles. His dissertation gives a five-page definition of an ordinal function, this would have been the longest in this answer, however I decided to omit it as it is for analyzing the stronger system $\Pi_\omega\text-\mathsf{Ref}$ only, unlike Arai's which may be restricted to an $N=4$ case.

The downside of Rathjen's approach is … additional complexity when trying to extend it (especially beyond $\Pi_3$-reflection) …. Even more recent systems along these lines are fairly complex. For examples, see (Duchhardt 2008) for $\Pi_4$ reflection, (Arai 2015) for $\Pi_n$ reflection, and (Stegert 2010) for stability.

~ Taranovsky giving an overview of the (at the time) state of the art in ordinal analysis, on his webpage "Ordinal Notation".

The Lie algebra $\operatorname{so}(4)$ splits into a direct product; $\operatorname{so}(3)$ doesn't.

Can you add what you mean by $\operatorname{so}(n)$? Because it is lowercase it might now be as universally known.

@M.Winter, I think lowercase (or lowercase Fraktur/Sütterlin) is reasonably common for Lie algebras, which may have been why the poster left it out, but I went ahead and edited to remove any confusion.

On page 12 of the IHES preprint version of "Chirurgie des Grassmanniennes" by Laurent Lafforgue, he mentions that a certain morphism related to compactifications of ${\rm PGL}_{n}^{4}/{\rm PGL}_n$ is smooth for $n\le 3$ and then fails to be flat for $n=4$ and above.

When g ≤ 3, every principally polarized abelian variety of dimension g is the Jacobian of a curve of genus g, but most are not for g ≥ 4.

For each $d \le 3$, there are plenty of smooth projective plane curves of degree $d$ with infinitely many rational points, but for $d \ge 4$ there are none.

Cute, although slightly cheating, since it's really a change from $$g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}\le1$$ to $$g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}\ge2.$$ So it's a hidden $2$ to $3$ change.

@Joe, of course! Like my answer to the related 2 vs. 3 question asked recently, I just figured I'd post something simple and not to be taken too seriously.

Typo (pointed out by John), I should have said a hidden "1 to 2" change.

Distinct tilings of space by both the measure polytope and the cross polytope exist only in four dimensions (the measure and cross polytopes are identical in one or two dimensions).
Measure polytopes always tile space, but cross polytopes do not. For instance, in three dimensions cubes tile space but regular octahedra do not (unless supplemented by regular tetrahedra). In $n$ dimensions, the dihedral angle $\theta$ between adjacent cells satsifies $\cos\theta=(2/n)-1$; this corresponds to $\theta$ dividing $360°$ evenly only for $n=1$ or $2$ (where as mentioned the cross polytope reduces to the measure polytope) and for $n=4$.

4 is the smallest composite number.

I do not know why this took so long.
